# Complex JSON to Map

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-web

I am fetching a data from API and the response is as below

```
[{_id: 60adf4f56de76a8669ca6089, createdDate: 2021-05-26T07:12:53.928Z, name: Save, lastUpdatedDate: 2021-05-26T14:26:17.922Z, __v: 0, pageProperties: {0: {color: Color(0xffde0404)}}}]
```

I am using the following code to convert into Map

```
List data = json.decode(response.body);
    data.forEach((element) {
      Map object = element;
      print(object['pageProperties']); 
      Map properties = object['pageProperties']; //getting error here
      print(properties);
    });
```

It sucessfully prints 'print(object['pageProperties']);' as '{0: {color: Color(0xffde0404)}}'
but now I am unable to parse '{0: {color: Color(0xffde0404)}}'

I am getting error as 'Expected a value of type 'Map<dynamic, dynamic>', but got one of type 'String''

How can I convert '{0: {color: Color(0xffde0404)}}' to Map<int,Map<String,dynamic>

Comment: Can you paste the raw data? that is, with quotation marks, to see how really the data is being delivered.

Answer (score 0):

You need to try work with this value as a string and decode it, for example:

```dart
final properties = json.decode(object['pageProperties']);
// Do something with properties here
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's suppose the "pageProperties" contains more properties of a page like color, page index etc..

First you need to make a model of that.

```
   class PageProperties{

   String color;
   int pageIndex;
 

  PageProperties(
  this.color,
  this.pageIndex,
  );

PageProperties.fromJson(Map<String,dynamic> json){

color= json['color'];
pageIndex= json['pageIndex'];
}

Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
final Map<String, dynamic> data = new Map<String, dynamic>();

data['color'] = this.color;
data['pageIndex'] = this.pageIndex;

return data;
 }
}
```

**Now the above two functions are there to ease up the conversion from and to JSON.**

Now Let's take you have this list of pageProperties as variable of some class so just do this.

```
Class Some{
  
 List<PageProperties> list;
 Some(this.pageProperties);
 

 Some.fromJson(Map<String,dynamic> json)
  {
   list = List<PageProperties>.from(
      jsonDecode(json['pageProperties']).map((model) =>
          PageProperties.fromJson(model)));
    }
  }
```

Now what is above line doing is that it takes the JSON parameter "pageProperties" and then
decode it which converts it to Map<String,dynamic> and then converting every child of map into PagePropeties using **.fromJson** function we created.

You can do this for everytime and it is a very good practice for making code short.